# How to identify the recurring payments that happen after the initial subs creation payment the in Commerce Subs

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2, plugin-commerce-stripe

I've got a custom module that I have written to inject data into various places in my site when events happen with Commerce Subs.

As per the question title, I need to update an entry when a recurring payment happens (not the initial payment as I'm already doing something with that event).

I cannot see how to identify the subsequent payments from the events I have available to me in Craft Commerce

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook and check the `billing_reason` for `subscription_cycle`. Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165193/1215040

```
use craft\commerce\stripe\base\Gateway as StripeGateway;
use craft\commerce\stripe\events\ReceiveWebhookEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    StripeGateway::class,
    StripeGateway::EVENT_RECEIVE_WEBHOOK,
    function(ReceiveWebhookEvent $e) {

        if ($e->webhookData['type'] == 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
            $invoice = $e->webhookData['data']['object'];
            if ($invoice['billing_reason'] == 'subscription_cycle') {
                // It's not the first payment!
            }
            if ($invoice['billing_reason'] == 'subscription_create') {
                // It's the first payment!
            }
        }
    }
);
```